# How to select all in PrimeFaces TreeTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treetable

I have a PrimeFaces tree table and would like to add a check box which allows the user to select/unselect all.

Here is an extract from my xhtml

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox
        itemLabel="Select all"                                      
        value="#{mainViewBean.selectAll}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{mainViewBean.onSelectAll}"
            update="@this :mainForm" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>  

    <p:treeTable id="treeToAssign"
        value="#{mainViewBean.treeValue}" var="vh"
        selectionMode="checkbox"
        selection="#{mainViewBean.treeSelection}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Tree Table                                                  
        </f:facet>                                                              
        <p:column>                                      
            <h:outputText value="#{vh.name}" />
        </p:column>                                 
    </p:treeTable>
```

and here is my bean method

```
private TreeNode treeValue;
private TreeNode[] treeSelection;
private boolean selectAll;

public void onSelectAll() {             
    List<TreeNode> selection = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TreeNode node : treeValue.getChildren()) {
    node.setSelected(selectAll);
        selection.add(node);
    }

    treeSelection = selection.toArray(new TreeNode[selection.size()]);
}
```

I had initially tried just setting `NODE.setSelected(selectAll);`, but that didn't work so I tried manually manually filling `treeSelection` as well.

I feel like this should be straightforward, but have been unable to figure it out, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically PrimeFaces uses the term node in the treeTable to refer to each row, and it provides a javascript function [PrimeFaces.widget.TreeTable.selectNodesInRange(node)](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/907f0a6d49ae50223cc98074b55b5d10d80c8764/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/treetable/treetable.js#L385) for selecting all the nodes in a rage of another node, and also another function to unselect all the nodes [PrimeFaces.widget.TreeTable.unselectAllNodes()](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/907f0a6d49ae50223cc98074b55b5d10d80c8764/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/treetable/treetable.js#L374).

Thus, having the following function (for selecting all, no need to have one for unselecting, it's already present):

```
function selectAllInTreeTable(widgetVar) {
   widgetVar.tbody.find('tr').each(function() {
      widgetVar.selectNodesInRange($(this));
   });
}
```

and assuming your `widgetVar` for the treeTable is `treeTableWV`, and adjusting the selectAll booleanCheckbox into this:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox widgetVar="selectAllCheckBox" onchange="PF('selectAllCheckBox').isChecked()?PF('treeTableWV').unselectAllNodes():selectAllInTreeTable(PF('treeTableWV'))" >
   ...
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Would do it.

Comment: Just had to change to select all when isChecked and unselectAll otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- Make your bean at least `@ViewScoped`
- Create additional field `private Set<TreeNode> selectedNodesSet = new HashSet<>();`
- Use recursion for selecting/deselecting

```java
public void onSelectAll() {
    for (TreeNode node : treeValue.getChildren()) {
        recursiveSelect(node);
    }

    treeSelection = new TreeNode[selectedNodesSet.size()];
    Iterator<TreeNode> iterator = selectedNodesSet.iterator();
    int index = 0;

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        treeSelection[index++] = iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
    }
}

private void recursiveSelect(TreeNode node) {
    node.setSelected(selectAll);

    if (selectAll) {
        selectedNodesSet.add(node);
    } else {
        selectedNodesSet.remove(node);
    }

    for (TreeNode n : node.getChildren()) {
        recursiveSelect(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has worked to an extent. With logging/debugging I can see that the nodes are all being selected, but the checkboxes aren't being visibly ticked on screen. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: The line `node.setSelected(selectAll);` should check them. You can iterate over nodes and check if they are selected after execution of `recursiveSelect` for loop. Also try adding `@form` or even `@all` to `update="@this :mainForm"` and see if maybe there lies the problem.